# Javascript - Incasesensitif split() without using toLowerCase() or toUpperCase()

Tags: javascript, string

I'm trying to split a `string` using `split()` method but it work case-sensitifly, the question is as typed on the title.

The problem is like this

```
var str, ret;

str = "NubNubLabaLabaNubNub";
ret = str.split("labalaba"); // ret return ["NubNubLabaLabaNubNub"]

// which i wanted ["NubNub","NubNub"]
```

When i using `toLowerCase()` or `toUpperCase()` the whole `string` will change, and after spliting i want it to be an original one.

```
str = "NubNubLabaLabaNubNub";
ret = str.toLowerCase().split("labalaba".toLowerCase());
```

`ret` return `["nubnub","nubnub"]` but the result that i wanted is `["NubNub","NubNub"]`

I still not understand how to return the `"nubnub"` to `"NubNub"`

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use a case-insensitive regular expression instead:

```js
const str = "NubNubLabaLabaNubNub";
console.log(
  str.split(/labalaba/i)
);
```

If the string to split on is in a variable, [escape it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3561493/is-there-a-regexp-escape-function-in-javascript) first, then pass it to `new RegExp`:

```js
const escape = s => s.replace(/[-\/\\^$*+?.()|[\]{}]/g, '\\$&');

const str = "abcfoo()barabc";
const splitOn = 'foo()bar';
const re = new RegExp(escape(splitOn), 'i');
console.log(
  str.split(re)
);
```

Comment: above work fine
but how if the split() parameter stored in variable?
like `spl = "labalaba"`? and executed like `str.split("/"+spl+"/i")` it seems not working.

Comment: See edit, escape the string, then pass it to `new RegExp`. (if there are no special characters in the string, then no need to escape it)

Comment: i'm actually have some more question, if the string that i replace incase-sensitifly are `"AsdE"` with `splitOn = "asde"`, how to record the `string` that we repleace are `"AsdE"` not `"asde"` or `"ASDE"`?